# Unity3d Raycast not hitting mesh collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have looked through the forums and nothing can explain or help with what is going on. I have been using Unity3d for the past 8 years and this one has me stumped. I have drawn the ray if the object is not hit and from this image you can see that its hitting it. Also I created a primitive sphere to see if i could drag the sphere along the red line and it does hit with scale being 1.

[image]

[image]
[image]
Code below broke everything down to be simple

```
    public void CastRay()
    {
        var Cam = Camera.main; //added this in for stackoverflow completeness 
        var ray = new Ray(Cam.transform.position, Cam.transform.forward);
        if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, 1, out RaycastHit hit))
        {
            Debug.Log($"HIT SOMETHING {hit.transform.name}");
        } else {
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 1000, Color.red, 20000);
        }
    }
```

this class is raised in my code to call the example code above

```
//usage ThreadCrossOver.Instance.RaiseAction(CastRay); <-- called from else where
public class ThreadCrossOver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ThreadCrossOver Instance{
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = FindObjectOfType<ThreadCrossOver>();
            }
            return instance;
    };
    private static ThreadCrossOver instance;        
    private readonly Queue<Action> actions = new Queue<Action>();
    private static readonly object it = new object();

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (actions.Count == 0) return;
        while (actions.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (it) actions.Dequeue().Invoke();
        }        
    }
    public void RaiseAction(Action action)
    {
        lock(it) actions.Enqueue(action);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be casting a `RayCast` instead of a `SphereCast`? Also, should it really be in `Start()` method?

Comment: Afaik in `Start` the Physics might not all pre-calculated ... is your object spawned on runtime?

Comment: The above was an example I am running the code from Update, awe maybe LateUpdate would be better. Basically the portion that im doing above is called from a thread but I had to put the cast back onto the main thread. I will try LateUpdate and get back to you guys. I updated the question above with my Class that puts the call back onto the main thread, going to change that update to LateUpdate.

Comment: Same difference, it was a good thought though. Also it does detect other objects but I am thinking that these models are strange, I will add another image to show what I mean

Comment: Also the object is created at runtime. It is done before the Raycast has started I slowed it down frame by frame to be sure. Also added a breakpoint before the cast takes place.

Comment: Turns out I had to wait for a second in a Corroutine thank you derHugo.